# Good reference for self study of Gauge theory

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, fibration, gauge-theory, holonomy

I am looking for the shortest way possible to study basic gauge theory. I am looking for some inspiring survey notes like this one: [Christian Bär, Gauga Theory](https://www.math.uni-potsdam.de/fileadmin/user_upload/Prof-Geometrie/Dokumente/Lehre/Lehrmaterialien/skript-Eichtheo.pdf) (rather than the great books by Kobayashi & Nomizu or Steenrod). Dealing, in particular, with:

- Problem of lifting 'basic' paths to horizontal paths.
- Why the reduction of the structural group is important.
- Links between: trivial bundle, flat bundle, $G$-local system

Comment: Why is it down-voted? I can edit the question so it fits the general rules of the forum!

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but I voted to close this under the "Needs more focus" heading, because it contains more than one question.

Comment: @SuzuHirose It's done

Answer (score 4):

David Bleeckers Gauge Theory and Variational Principles is the quickest and dirtiest introduction to gauge theory I know. It’s pretty physics motivated but definitely doesn’t skimp on the math, and should deal with those first two points, though I’m not sure about the third explicitly.

A longer text is mathematical gauge theory by Hamilton, but if you’re already cool with Lie groups, basic representation theory, and quotient manifolds you could jump right into chapter 4 (fiber bundles and principal bundles) and read through to chapter 5 (connections and curvature).

Another longer text is Bruce Sontz’s Principal Bundles the classical case. I have less to say about this one (I mostly used to read through certain topics pertaining to connections in a different), but it’s a refreshing text, that employs some category theory if you’re interested in that at all. It also has a sequel that I have  yet to look at, Principal Bundles the quantum case.

Another shorter text that’s completely physics motivated is Gauge Fields, Knots, Gravity by John Baez. I have found this one interesting but not great for a first introduction for the mathematics because it’s a little too focused on physics.

Comment: Many thanks, these books are very nice!